# Push function in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, push

In the below code, When I push each line into an array (@num), I found that a single space is being added to the end of the line while passing in to array.

There is no space at the end of line in my input file. I found this single space when I print all elements in the array.

```
open (A, "file.txt");
my @num = ();

while(my $each=<A>)
{
    chomp $each;
    $each=~s/\s//g;
    push(@num,$each);
}
close(A);
```

Can some one help me on this?

Comment: How are you printing the elements of the array?  Because I'll bet $.25 that that's where the problem is.

Comment: It is not possible for you to have a "single space" at the end of your lines, since you do `$each=~s/\s//g;` for each line, which removes *all* whitespace from each line. So... no.

Comment: How are you printing "all elements in the array?" You should use `Data::Dumper` to inspect the contents of `@num`, e.g. `print Dumper(\@num), "\n"`

Comment: I use this print statement: print @num;

Comment: @Iam `print @num` would mean that no whitespace is added, since the default value for `$,` is the empty string. So... no. Your question is moot. It cannot happen. You need to post some code which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Note that `print @num` and `print "@num"` are different.  My money remains on you misreporting how you are printing the array, though someone changing `$OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR` behind your back is a vague possibility.  In either case, use `Data::Dumper` to see what your strings *actually* contain.

Answer (score 5):

You shouls *always*

- Add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your program, and declare all your variables with `my` at their point of first use
- Use the three-parameter form of `open` and lexical filehandles
- Check the status of each open to make sure it succeeded

The code you show won't add any spaces to your lines. Is there any more to your program?

Your code is better written as

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @num = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
  <$fh>;
};

s/\s+//g for @num;
```

**Update**

As [@darch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9719/darch) commented, are you writing

```
print "@num\n";
```

or something similar? That will put spaces *between* each element of the array, and should be written

```
print @num, "\n";
```

Comment: I use this print statement: print @num;

Comment: Then you must show us your complete program. The problem is not in the part you have shown

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets diagnose this.

First install [`Data::Printer`](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aPrinter). This module is like Data::Dumper but meant for humans.

Then after all your code add these lines.

```
use DDP;
p $,;
p $";
p @num;
```

on my computer this does

```
undef
" "
[
    [0] "a",
    [1] "b",
    [2] "c"
]
```

I used `@num = (qw/a b c/);` for my `@num` btw.

Anyway, this module does a good job of quoting strings so that you can see trailing spaces. `$,` is the string that gets put between elements in a non-quoted list. `$"` is the string that gets put between elements in a quoted list.

Tell us the results of these tests and hopefully that helps track things down.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) to print array elements which are added from input file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open (A, "file.txt");
my @num;

while(my $each=<A>)
{
    chomp $each;
    $each=~s/\s//g;
    push(@num,$each);
}
close(A);

print Dumper(@num);
```

Theoutput i got is proper, like this

```
$VAR1 = 'abcdefghi';
$VAR2 = 'jklmnioqrstuvwxyz';
$VAR3 = '1234554';
```